# Flowchart drawing ( Arrows)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

How can I add the  arrows as shown in the above flowchart ?
The main problem is that, I don't know how to draw the rest of the arrows, especially, the north-northwest and north-north east .
If possible help me putting these arrows  or if possible propose another way.

The code:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.3cm,bottom=1.3cm]{geometry}
    
    % Required packages
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
        calc, chains,
        decorations.pathreplacing,%
        calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
        positioning,
        shapes}
    \definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
    \definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
    \definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
    \definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
    \definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}
    \definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                node distance = 4mm and 12mm,
                start chain = A going below,
                arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=3mm, width=6mm]}, line width= 2mm,
                    draw=blue2, shorten > = 1mm, shorten <=1mm},
                BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
                    decorate,
                    decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                        raise=#1,
                        #2},% for mirroring of brace
                    very thick,
                    pen colour={#3} },
                N/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                    fill=#1,draw=blue2,
                    minimum height=8mm, text width=80mm,
                    align=flush center},
                N1/.style = {draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                    fill=#1,
                    minimum height=8mm, text width=50mm,
                    align=flush center},
                N2/.style={draw,text width=3cm ,text centered,
                    minimum width=4cm,fill=yellow1,tape, tape bend top=none,tape bend height=1.1mm,   tape bend bottom=in and out,
                    minimum height=1.1cm}  ,
                N3/.style = {diamond,   minimum width=6.5cm, minimum height=2mm, text centered, draw=blue2, fill=blue2},
                N5/.style = {draw=blue2, text centered, ellipse,text width= 40mm, fill=blue2, node distance=8cm, minimum height=15mm},
                N4/.style = {rectangle, text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered ,fill=gray2}]
                % main branch
                \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A}]
                    \node [N1=blue1,draw=blue1]     {ETAPES};                   % A-1
                    \node [N=blue2,below=2cm of A-1]   {Event recording};    % A-2
                    \node [N=blue2]     {Implementation of a           correction if possible};
                    \node [N=blue2]     {Event qualification};
                    \node [N3=blue2] {Treatment necessary ? };
                    \node [N=blue2]     {Research of the causes and hierarchization };
                    \node [N=blue2]     {Definition of the action plan and responsibilities};
                    \node [N=blue2]     {Decision and implementation of reporting to authorities };
                    \node  [N3=blue2,text width= 30mm] {Implementation and effectiveness of the actions};
                    \node [N5=blue2]     {Event closing};
                \end{scope}
                
                % nodes on the left side of the main branch
                
                \node [N1=gray1,draw=gray1, 
                left=19 mm of A-1]     (B-1)   {ACTEURS};
                \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2, 
                left=of A-2]     (B-2)   {Collaborator};
            
                \coordinate (aux1) at ($(A-2.south west)!0.5!(A-4.north west)$);
                \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray2]   (A-2.west) -- (A-4.west);
                \node [N4=gray2,left=of aux1,draw=gray2 ,text width=3.5cm]     (B-4)    {Support team (\+RA\&QM)};
                \coordinate (aux2) at ($(A-6.south west)!0.5!(A-7.north west)$);
                    \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray2]   (A-6.west) -- (A-7.west);
            
                \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
                left=of aux2]     (B-6)   {Assigned team + RA\&QM};
                \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
                left=of A-8]     (B-7)   {COO };
                \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
                left=of A-9]     (B-8)   {RA\&QM};
                \node [N4=gray2,draw=gray2,  
                left=of A-10]     (B-9)   {Assigned team + RA\&QM };
                
                % nodes on the right side of thr main branch
                \begin{scope}[N/.append style={text width=44mm},
                    N/.default=yellow1]
                    \node[N1=yellow1,draw=yellow1,  right=19mm of A-1]     (C-1)   {DOCUMENTS};
                    \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-2]     (C-2)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
                    \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-4]     (C-3)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
                    \node[N1=yellow1,draw=yellow1,  right=18mm of A-1]     (C-3)   {DOCUMENTS};
                    \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-6]     (C-4)   {FOR\_01\_M02};
                    \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-7]     (C-5)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
                    \node[N2,draw=yellow1, right=of A-8]     (C-6)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
                    \node[draw=blue2, text centered, ellipse,text width=30mm, fill=blue2, node distance=2cm, minimum height=18mm,right=1cm of A-5]   (C-7)  {Filing};
                \end{scope}
                %arrows 
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-9) - ++(4.5,0)  |- (A-6)  node[near start,anchor=west]{No};
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-5) -- (C-7)  node[near start,anchor=south] {No};
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-5) -- (A-6)  node[near start,anchor=west] {yes};
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-9) -- (A-10)  node[near start,anchor=west] {yes};
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-2) -- (A-3)  ;
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-3) -- (A-4)  ;
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-4) -- (A-5)  ;
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-6) -- (A-7)  ;
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-7) -- (A-8)  ;
            \draw[black,ultra thick,-latex] (A-8) -- (A-9)  ;
        
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
            \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141502]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                shapes}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{84,141,212}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{142,180,227}
\definecolor{yellow1}{RGB}{255,229,153}
\definecolor{orange1}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{gray1}{RGB}{127,127,127}
\definecolor{gray2}{RGB}{217,217,217}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 4mm and 12mm,
   start chain = A going below,
    arr/.style = {-{Triangle[length=2mm, width=4mm]},
            line width=1mm, draw=blue2},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{
            decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                        raise=#1,
                        #2},% for mirroring of brace
            very thick,
            pen colour={#3} },
      N/.style = {draw=#1, semithick, rounded corners,
            fill=#1,draw=blue2,
            minimum height=8mm, text width=54mm,
            align=flush center},
    N1/.style = {N=#1},
    N2/.style = {tape, tape bend top=none,
            tape bend height=1.1mm, tape bend bottom=in and out,draw,
            draw, fill=yellow1,
            text width=4cm, align=center,
            minimum height=1.1cm},
    N3/.style = {diamond, aspect=2,
            text width=44mm, align=flush center,
            draw=blue2, fill=blue2},
    N4/.style = {fill=gray2,
            text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
    N5/.style = {ellipse, draw=blue2, fill=blue2,
            text width= 40mm, minimum height=15mm, align=center},
                    ]
% main branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node [N1=blue1]     {ETAPES};          % A-1
\node [below=2cm of A-1,
       N=blue2]     {Event recording};  % A-2
\node [N=blue2]     {Implementation of a correction if possible};
\node [N=blue2]     {Event qualification};
\node [N3=blue2]    {Treatment necessary ? };
\node [N=blue2]     {Research of the causes and hierarchization };
\node [N=blue2]     {Definition of the action plan and responsibilities};
\node [N=blue2]     {Decision and implementation of reporting to authorities };
\node [N3]          {Implementation and effectiveness of the actions};
\node [N5=blue2]    {Event closing};
    \end{scope}

% nodes on the left side of the main branch
\node [N1=gray1,
       left=of A-1] (B-1)   {ACTEURS};
    \begin{scope}[N4/.default=gray2]
\node[N4, at={(A-2 -| B-1)}]    (B-2)   {Collaborator};
\coordinate[at={($(A-2.south west)!0.5!(A-4.north west)$)}] (aux1);
    \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray]   (A-2.west) -- (A-4.west);
\node [N4, left=of aux1]        (B-4)   {Support team (+RA\&QM)};
\coordinate[at={($(A-6.south west)!0.5!(A-7.north west)$)}] (aux2);
    \draw[BC=4mm/mirror/gray]   (A-6.west) -- (A-7.west);
\node [N4, left=of aux2]        (B-6)   {Assigned team + RA\&QM};
\node [N4, at={(A-8 -| B-1)}]   (B-7)   {COO };
\node [N4, at={(A-9 -| B-1)}]   (B-8)   {RA\&QM};
\node [N4, at={(A-10 -| B-1)}]  (B-9)   {Assigned team + RA\&QM };
    \end{scope}
% nodes on the right side of thr main branch
\node[N1=yellow1,
      right=of A-1]     (C-1)   {DOCUMENTS};
    \begin{scope}[N2/.default=yellow1]
\node[N2, at={(A-2 -| C-1)}]    (C-2)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
\node[N2, at={(A-4 -| C-1)}]    (C-4)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
\node[N5, text width=32mm,
          at={(A-5 -| C-1)}]    (C-5)   {Filing};
\node[N2, at={(A-6 -| C-1)}]    (C-6)   {FOR\_01\_M02};
\node[N2, at={(A-7 -| C-1)}]    (C-7)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
\node[N2, at={(A-8 -| C-1)}]    (C-8)   {FOR\_01\_M02 };
    \end{scope}
%arrows
\draw[arr]  (A-9.east) -- node[above] {No} ++(0.8,0)
                  |- (A-6);
\draw[arr]  (A-5) -- node[above] {No}    (C-5);
\path       (A-5) -- node[right=2mm]  {yes}   (A-6)
            (A-9) -- node[right=2mm]  {yes}   (A-10);
% new nodes above "event recording"
    \begin{scope}[every path/.style = {arr, shorten > = 3mm}]
\path (A-2.150) ++ (150:11mm) node[above left] {complaints} -- (A-2)
      (A-2.120) ++ (120:13mm) node[above left] {feedbacks}  -- (A-2)
      (A-2.60) ++ (60:13mm) 
                node[above right]   {Product non-comfornity} -- (A-2)
     (A-2.30) ++ (30:11mm)
                node[above right]   {System non-comfornity}  -- (A-2);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i needed